# Summing a years worth of data that spans two years pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains data similar to this:

```
Name    Date        A   B   C
John    19/04/2018  10  11  8
John    20/04/2018  9   7   9
John    21/04/2018  22  15  22
…   …       …   …   …
John    16/04/2019  8   8   9
John    17/04/2019  10  11  18
John    18/04/2019  8   9   11
Rich    19/04/2018  18  7   6
…   …       …   …   …
Rich    18/04/2019  19  11  17
```

The data can start on any day and contains at least 365 days of data, sometimes more. What I want to end up with is a DataFrame like this:

```
Name    Date    Sum
John    April   356
John    May     276
John    June    209
Rich    April   452
```

I need to sum up all of the months to get a year’s worth of data (April - March) but I need to be able to handle taking part of April’s total (in this example) from 2018 and part from 2019. What I would also like to do is shift the days so they are consecutive and follow on in sequence so rather than:

```
John    16/04/2019  8   8   9   Tuesday
John    17/04/2019  10  11  18  Wednesday
John    18/04/2019  8   9   11  Thursday
John    19/04/2019  10  11  8   Thursday (was 19/04/2018)
John    20/04/2019  9   7   9   Friday (was 20/04/2018)
```

It becomes

```
John    16/04/2019  8   8   9   Tuesday
John    17/04/2019  10  11  18  Wednesday
John    18/04/2019  8   9   11  Thursday
John    19/04/2019  9   7   9   Friday (was 20/04/2018)
```

Prior to summing to get the final DataFrame. Is this possible?

*Additional information requested in comments*

Here is a link to the initial data set https://github.com/stottp/exampledata/blob/master/SOExample.csv and the required output would be:

```
Name Month Total 
John March  11634 
John April  11470 
John May    11757 
John June   10968 
John July   11682 
John August 11631 
John September 11085 
John October 11924 
John November 11593 
John December 11714 
John January 11320 
John February 10167 
Rich March 11594 
Rich April 12383 
Rich May 12506 
Rich June 11112 
Rich July 11636 
Rich August 11303 
Rich September 10667 
Rich October 10992 
Rich November 11721 
Rich December 11627 
Rich January 11669 
Rich February 10335
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the samples.  Can you provide the initial data in a form that can be easily pasted into someone else's code (`df = pd.DataFrame`) along with the desired output *that matches that input*?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. I've added the information you requested in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understood correctly. If you want to sum, I suppose you mean sum the values of columns ['A', 'B', 'C'] for each day and get the total value monthly.

If that's right, the first thing to to is set the ['Date'] column as the index so that the data frame is easier to work with:

```
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True, drop=True)
del df['Date']
```

Next, you will want to add the new column ['Sum'] by re-sampling your data frame (from days to months) whilst summing the values of ['A', 'B', 'C']:

```
df['Sum'] = df['A'].resample('M').sum() + df['B'].resample('M').sum() + df['C'].resample('M').sum()
df['Sum'].head()

Out[37]: 
Date
2012-11-30    1956265
2012-12-31    2972076
2013-01-31    2972565
2013-02-28    2696121
2013-03-31    2970687
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

The last part about squashing February of 2018 and 2019 together as if they were a single month might yield from:

```
df['2019-02'].merge(df['2018-02'], how='outer', on=['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Test this last step and see if it works for you.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That solution would provide a monthly breakdown and would yield a result for February 2018 and February 2019. With February 2018 containing data from the 7th to 28th and February 2019 would contain data from the 1st to the 26th. What I would like is for only one February to be output, containing 26 days from 2019 and 2 days from 2018 with the correct sequence of days

Comment: I see. Checkout out my edit and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked for, but I figure you could do some tinkering to figure this one out. Hint: use the las part of my code to create a new Series with the data you want. =)

Comment: @Ron - has my answer been useful to you? If so, please upvote or accept it, please.